# Inserting to a sqlite database in windows 8 store app always return "Busy"

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I'm trying to follow the following article: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/import-an-already-existing-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-application/

I have the following class that will copy the existing sqlite database:

```
public class DataHandler
    {
        public static string GetPath()
        {
            return ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\myDB";
        }

        public async void CopyDatabase()
        {
            bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

            try
            {
                StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myDB");
                isDatabaseExisting = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                isDatabaseExisting = false;
            }

            if (!isDatabaseExisting)
            {
                StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("myDB");
                await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can successfully query the database using the following code:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DataHandler.GetPath());
            var query = conn.Table<appSetting>().Where(x => x.appSettingId == id);
            var result =  await query.ToListAsync();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                this.appSettingId = item.appSettingId;
                this.appVersion = item.appVersion;
            }
```

However whenever I try to do an insert using the following code, I always get a sqliteexception of "busy"

```
appSetting app = new appSetting{
                    appSettingId = 2,
                    appVersion = "2.0"
                };

                var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DataHandler.GetPath());
                var result = await conn.InsertAsync(app);
```

Any idea why this keep on happening?

Comment: What are the Grant rights setup as on that particular Database..? can you manually Insert a record..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE if I go to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\myDB" and open the sqlite database using SQLite Database Browser, I can insert data to it.

Comment: I think Tim Heuer's excellent example has become the gold standard in incorporating SQLite into Win 8 Apps.  http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, how it'll work in `c#`. Noramally, in `sqlite` if you opened your database, after your operations has been done you should `close` it.

In case, if you forgot to `close` your `sqlite database`, it'll keep itself busy.